# Stop accordion menu from opening and closing?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery for an accordion menu: http://jsfiddle.net/fPWeq/

```
rel = 0;
$('.sub-menu').hover(function(){ // findind mouse postion
        rel = 1; // if mouse on submenu
    }, function(){ 
        rel = 0;  // if mouse out submenu
});
$('.menu > li').live("click",function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){ // if not already opened
            $('.sub-menu').slideUp();    // hide all other submenu
            $('.sub-menu',this).slideDown();  // show which your clicked
            $(".menu > li").remove('active');  //  remove all active class in li
            $(this).addClass('active'); //adding active class which your clicked li
        }
        else{
            if(rel==0){
                $('.sub-menu').slideUp(); // if clicked already opend parent that will close
                $(this).removeClass('active'); // remove all active class
            }
            else{
            }
        }
});
;​
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to stop active (pre-opened) submenus from closing and opening again when sub menu links within are clicked.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

remove  `class="current-parent"`
and it shouldnt show the sub open.
Check here http://jsfiddle.net/fPWeq/1/

Comment: I want the sub to be pre-open. I just don't want it to close and then open again when a sub link is clicked.

Comment: Give `class="current-parent"` a class active so it becomes `class="current-parent active"`

Comment: did it help? Was it the answer to your problem?

Comment: hi I am trying to figure out how to add active class. It seems to work in jsfiddle, but not on my site for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

Also [`.toggleClass("current-parent")`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) can be a good choice if you want to activate the opening/closing again.